# Type error on ViewModelProviders#of in preferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-room, android-livedata

I am **Building** a Setting Screen with **Preference Fragment**. One of the view when clicked opens a dialog box with **recyclerView** in it.

I want to pop up the **live data from the room database** in it ,  Using **Google architecture model** .

I have used **repository model** with **view model** from which i will **call** my **live data** object .

But in  onCreate Method , when i call ViewModelProvide.of(this) it throws me error .

> Can not resolve the method of (com.example.SettingPreferenceFragment)

Code :

```
       SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SettingsViewModel.class);
```

How to use Live data in Preference Fragment ?

Comment: cast your SettingPreferenceFragment to Fragment and pass it to ViewModelProviders

Comment: @Vishal  .I am not able to cast preferenceFragment to fragment.  Its throwing me the error in android studio.  "inconvertible type's , cannot cast preferenceFragment to fragment  "